# field to explode in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I do have something like   California|Washington  in mytable where values are concatenated by separator |

```
query:  select state from mytable
result: California|Washington
```

and I would like to get each value in a row like

California

Washington

so I can make join to another table containing

```
id  state         population
1   California    489283
2   Washington    923829
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Don't store data like concatenated values!!! It will only cause you lots of trouble. Use separete rows (or columns) for separate values!!!

Comment: I know, I wouldn't design like this, but unfortunate, I am working in a DB already designed by someone else, and not an option to change anything

Comment: UNION the table with itself, where you select substring first part from table 1, and substring second part from table 2.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in a single query? Or is it an option to use a scripting language?

Comment: unfortunately necessary to do it in a single query, and not an option to use scripting language or any procedure,

Comment: Table definitions and sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store data in this way. However, if you can't change it due to legacy reason you can still do your query using LIKES.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM joined_table A,
        state_table S
  WHERE S.state LIKE CONCAT('%|', A.state, '|%')
     OR S.state LIKE CONCAT(A.state, '|%')
     OR S.state LIKE CONCAT('%|', A.state)
```

The conditions could be simpler if you always store the data enclosed by the separator character:

```
query:  select state from mytable
result: |California|Washington|
```

Then your query would be:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM joined_table A,
        state_table S
  WHERE S.state LIKE CONCAT('%|', A.state, '|%')
```